# VSCode shortcut to align text via multi cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is it possible to align text in VSCode like below

From -

```
customer as cust,
address   as addr,
phone as phonenum,
kirk     as kirk,
```

To -

```
customer  as cust,
address   as addr,
phone     as phonenum,
kirk      as kirk,
```

I tried multi-cursor but is it possible to select `as` and then a way to bring all in alignment?

Comment: Not a built-in way, but there are a bunch of extensions that can do that.  Just search in the extensions for `align`.

Answer (score 2):

- select all the `as`
- `Arrow Left` moves all cursors before `as`
- type a whole lot of spaces
- `Home` to move to the start of the lines
- `Arrow Right` until you are past the longest text before `as`
- `Ctrl+Delete` to delete the spaces until `as`

Comment: the difference in spacing still exists. the last step deletes the spaces only till the first occurance of `as` in a row.

Comment: @DrCare that is exactly the result you show in the `To`